# Getting Unknown MySQL server host in Django

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services

I have a MySQL RDS instance with Amazon's AWS as the database for my Django app. When I do run the command `python manage.py runserver 192.68.1.103:8000`, I get this error:

```
(2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'myapp.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (2)")
```

I can connect to the database using MySQL Workbench though. When I run the app through Apache, there are no problems either. I tried restarting the RDS instance but that didn't resolve the issue.

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: Just confirming that you know that `myapp.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` doesn't actually resolve to anything. I assume you have simply replaced the string with something more generic for demonstration purposes?

Comment: @cwallenpoole Yes, I just replaced the string with something generic.

Comment: I could swear that I've seen this issue before.

Comment: @cwallenpoole How'd you resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried the IP directly? Have you verified that you are working on the same port?

Comment: You should check that the security group of the RDS instance allows connections from the EC2 security group / external IP address that you're connecting from. You shouldn't try using the IP directly, as the IP will surely change over time.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced this on my local machine in some long running terminal (iTerm2) window. I'm not sure what it was but Django didn't resolve my db server name, maybe because of some DNS issues.

So running `./manage.py runserver` in another terminal solved the problem

Comment: Like magic... I'm also using iTerm2. Perhaps this is something they should be keen on. Thanks!

Comment: It happened the same to me, and I am using zsh

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue. Initially I was using the hostname:port in the HOST field from the configuration dictionary. When I changed it to have a separate field for the "port" everything worked well.

From this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ....
        'HOST': 'hostname:3306',
        'USER': 'username',
        ...
    },
}
```

I changed to this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ....
        'HOST': 'hostname',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'username',
        ....
    },
}
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was nothing wrong in the code, but my db data had somehow gotten corrupt. So I just reset the db and this error was resolved.